# Why doesn't Spike know Jerry in Puttin' On the Dog?

Tags: plot-explanation, sequels, tom-and-jerry

These two *Tom and Jerry* episodes were consecutive: *The Bodyguard* was released on July 22, 1944. *Puttin' On the Dog* was released about 3 months later on October 28, 1944. The plots are also related.

From the [IMDB](https://m.imdb.com/title/tt0037198/) website for *Puttin' On the Dog*:

> This cartoon is often considered to be a sequel to the previous Tom & Jerry cartoon, "The Bodyguard", since it was released after it and also because at the end of "The Bodyguard", Spike the bulldog is captured by a dog catcher while in this episode he is seen in a dog pound.

In the start scene of *The Bodyguard* Jerry rescues Spike from the dog catcher's truck and he promises Jerry to help him if he whistles for help. But at the end he is again captured by the dog catcher.

**My question**: Why doesn't Spike know Jerry in *Puttin' On the Dog*? He had helped him in the prior show.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every episode has to be reasonably self-contained. You never know what order people will see them in.

These cartoons weren't designed to be shown once on TV and never seen again, they were to cycle round and round at every matinee or Saturday morning cinema, world-wide, for decades. There were only 17 by the end of 1944, so they may have only run them every few weeks, or run them 10 times a day until the next was released.

Imagine even to this day, picking one random Simpson's episode of the current 750 in existence, as they now cycle round and round on many channels, and hope to remember what happened the episode before.

Comment: Yep. In the UK they used to be shown seemingly at random. Is there a 5-minute gap in the schedule? Let's stick in a Tom & Jerry cartoon.